# Looping over hard-coded values in specified in XSL stylesheet, not in XML

Tags: xslt

I'm wondering if there's a way to loop over a values **specified in the XSL**, rather than coming from the XML.

Let's say I have 3 possible checkboxes, with a "current" value that comes from the XML.  I'd have an XML doc like

```
<rootNode>
    <val>bar</val>
</rootNode>
```

and XSL code like

```
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" name="myvar" value="foo">
    <xsl:if test="val='foo'">
        <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</input> <label for="foo">foo</label>

<input id="bar" type="checkbox" name="myvar" value="bar">
    <xsl:if test="val='bar'">
        <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</input> <label for="bar">bar</label>

<input id="baz" type="checkbox" name="myvar" value="baz">
    <xsl:if test="val='baz'">
        <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</input> <label for="baz">baz</label>
```

This works, but the XSL is very verbose.  I'd LIKE to be able to do something like this:

```
<!-- this syntax doesn't work, is there something similar that does? -->
<xsl:variable name="boxNames" select="'foo','bar','baz'"/>
<xsl:for-each select="name in $boxNames">
    <input id="{$name}" type="checkbox" name="myvar" value="{$name}">
        <xsl:if test="val=$name">
            <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </input> <label for="{$name}"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></label>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I can KIND OF get this by putting the code in a template and using multiple `<call-template>` `<with-param>` calls, but that's doesn't save much space over the original.

Is there any concise way to do this with XSL?  I definitely can't put all the checkbox names in the XML output, it's a large list and unnecessarily bloats the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get the source (!) of the XSL by calling the `document('')` function, which you can then use as node datasource.

```
<xsl:template name="boxNames"> <!-- not used as template -->
  <name>foo</name>
  <name>bar</name>
  <name>baz</name>
</xsl:template>
```

[...]

```
<xsl:variable name="boxNames" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name='boxNames']/name" />
```

Comment: Instead of putting the data in an unused template, it can be put as a top-level element, provided that it uses some other namespace than the XSLT namespace. The XSLT processor will ignore such top-level elements.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i was hoping for!  I agree with Jukka, I'll use a separate namespace to reinforce that it's not actually a template.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, which is very close to the code you suggested:

```
<xsl:variable name="boxNames" select="'foo','bar','baz'"/>
<xsl:variable name="val" select="val"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$boxNames">
    <input id="{.}" type="checkbox" name="myvar" value="{.}">
        <xsl:if test="$val=.">
            <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </input> <label for="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></label>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It needs an XSLT 2.0 processor though.

Comment: I'd guessed XSLT 2.0 would make my dreams come true. :)  Unfortunately I have to support XSLT 1.0.  Still good to know though, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Template matches are effectively for-each loops.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates match="namespace:ItemName"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="namespace:ItemName">
    <input>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">checkbox</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">myvar</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select=".">
    </input>
    <label>
        <xsl:attribute name="for"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </label>
</xsl:template>
```

That should cut it down.

Comment: But that's pulling all the possible values, `namespace:ItemName`, from the XML, correct?  I specifically don't want to include all the possible values in every XML output, only the "current" value is in the XML.